# Map One View to Multiple Models

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.5

Is there any way, by which we can map one view to multiple Models?

Thanks & Regards
Sharad Kumar Sangal

Comment: It would help if you explained your use case.

Comment: Can you please be specific to Model and View name, it will be easy to suggest then. DXA has defined views and models wrt fields name for diff section of page. If you want your Single view to be shared across multiple model then you would end up having complex view with a lot of conditioning to choose sections to show on page. Not wise.